# Aggrid getEditingCells method not returning editing cells

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Ag grid has native ways of manipulating grid cells, but I'm facing issue with one such method grid.api.getEditingCells(). It is not returning the editing cells but other properties in the grid.api were working as normal. However I'm facing this issue only in some environments but it's working fine in some other environments and it seems this is the only method that isn't working. The property editingCell with the details is however working fine in all the environments so it is really frustrating why this method alone isn't working. Is it due to some kind of initialization issue or build issue. If so how can I resolve it

Tried using grid.api.getEditingCells() method and it should return the cells which are currently being edited after tabbing from one cell to the next one. But observed that it is returning an empty array in some environments and returning required values in some environments. Does it depend on build or some kind of grid initialization.  If it does how can I ensure appropriate behavior in all environments.